# Deduct product quantity after order is processed . Asp.Net MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, e-commerce, inventory-management

I would like to get product quantity number after order is processed.
For example:
Initial product quantity :50
order quantity : 10
Final product quantity = 50-10= 40

//Process Order Function

```
public ActionResult ProcessOrder(FormCollection frc)
    {
        List<Cart> lstCart = (List<Cart>)Session[strCart];
        Order order = new Order()
        {
            CustomerName = frc["cusName"],
            CustomerPhone = frc["cusPhone"],
            CustomerEmail = frc["cusEmail"],
            CustomerAddress = frc["cusAddress"],
            OrderName = "Grocery",
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
            PaymentType = "Cash",
            Status = "Processing"
        };

        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();

        try
        {
            foreach (Cart cart in lstCart)
            {
                OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail()
                {
                    OrderID = order.OrderID,
                    ProductID = cart.Product.pro_id,
                    Quantity = cart.Quantity,
                    Price = cart.Product.pro_unitPrice
                };

                //product pro = new product()
                //{
                //    pro_quantity = pro.pro_quantity- cart.Quantity 
                //};

                db.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            foreach (var errors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in errors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    // get the error message 
                    string errorMessage = validationError.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
        }

        Session.Remove(strCart);

        return View("OrderSuccess");
    }
}
```

[Entity Table of Product and Order Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rozTc.png)

Comment: ``cart.Product.pro_quantity`` contains the initial value of quantity?

Comment: The lines you comment for product, at that place you can fetch product details and subtract order item quantity and update same product with EF. But I suggest to update product after order detail added to database. so in case exception happen it wont reduce quantity

Comment: @Sajid yes, it contains value from check out product

Comment: so, ``pro_quantity `` will be calculate like ``pro_quantity = cart.Product.pro_quantity - cart.Quantity`` and register in base!